# How to extract image and title from website(iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-scraping, firebase

Am trying to make an iOS app like Pinterest where a user can save and share an online article. I would like the app to have the option to extract title and main image from a website article (Like Web Scraping) and save it in my Firebase database. The URL for the article will be provided by the user either by copy paste or through the SHARE Extension. I am a beginner to iOS development. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. Having a web view

What is the website article? If the website sets its html title (for this site: objective c - How to extract …) to the article title, you can use this one. You get it from the property [`pageTitle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebDataSource_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/WebDataSource/pageTitle) of a [web data source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebDataSource_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/WebDataSource). To get the web data source you have to ask the instance of a web frame. The web frames are ordered hierarchically and starts from the web view.

If you expect the article title to be enclosed in a `<h1>` tag or something like this, you have to query the document (see below).

Before one can answer how to get a "main image" from an article, you should define, what it is – using Objectice-C, PHP, Ruby, Swift or whatever.

B. Having no web view

You can directly load the html from the website with a url request and parse it your own. For the article usually [querying the document as XML document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/Articles/QueryingXML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001258-CJBFCGEG) works, even it is not technically correct.

For the "main image" look above.

Comment: Website article can be a webpage from any website. the point of the app is if a user sees a webpage he/she likes, he can share that with others. But for me to save that in my database, I need two parameters. The title of the webpage, and an image.

Comment: So you have a web view. Go ahead.

Comment: You're welcome. Please, mark the answer as correct, so others having a similar question will find it easily.